# Best way to store custom timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql

today i ran in to a problem,

i want to make a input field where people can select a date and put that date into my mysql database with the timestamp type. How can i do something like that

My database looks like this

[image]

Comment: Are you just asking how to insert data into a database?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried so many things, but at some way i cant get it so i make a form input type where you can choose the date and post that given date with insert to the database

Comment: Well, can you provide an example of something you've tried and explain in what way it didn't work as expected?  What debugging you've done and where specifically it fails?  Just asking how to insert data into a database is generally answered with "Start with a tutorial and try."

Comment: Thats a thing, it didnt worked so i deleted it

Comment: First, please show us the code you have written to try an accomplish this. Second, check the PHP manual for the date function. `$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   `

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

You need to store it in this format "Y-m-d H:i:s".

If it's not already in the above format use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class.

```
$userInput = "20/12/2016";
$date = DateTime::CreateFromFormat("d/m/Y", $userInput);
```

You'll now have a datetime object. With that you can format it using

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s);
```

Note: I'd personally use a DateTime field rather than a timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want.

```
$date =  $_POST['date'];
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

then insert `$timestamp` into your database.

Comment: this looks good, my input field than looks like <input type="date">?

Comment: the input could be any input type, text, date etc, but for the code to work it must be `name="date" `  in order to populate `$_POST['date']`

Answer (score -1):

The timestamp is inserted automatically as your date column in the database is flagged with

> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Just pass an empty value.

Comment: It is, but i want to make a html form where you can choose the date and put that date you choose into the database.

Comment: Then you have to alter your database first and remove that flag. Second thing is to format your input date properly and pass it in the mysql query then.

Comment: actually, you do not need to remove the current timestamp default. That's only used when no value is supplied, and could be handy for the people that pick today. Just make sure you insert dates in the correct format as Peck3277 points out